# Laravel dontReport in handler not working

Tags: laravel, exception, laravel-5

Laravel dontReport in handler file not working following code for dontReport

```
protected $dontReport = [
    Illuminate\Auth\AuthenticationException::class,
    Illuminate\Auth\Access\AuthorizationException::class,
    Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\HttpException::class,
    Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException::class,
    Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException::class,
    Illuminate\Validation\ValidationException::class,
    Illuminate\View\View::class,
    Illuminate\Routing\RouteCollection::class,
    Illuminate\Foundation\Http\Middleware\VerifyCsrfToken::class,
    Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
];
```

Comment: Add bit more context to your question. Ex. what are you trying to do and what you have implemented so far.

Comment: I am implementing error / exception reporting for laravel project when exception/ error occurred then at that time that exception /error reported with mail but that mail contains all exceptions/ error  which I want to exclude from mail

Answer (score 5):

Try to add this code in your `report` method:

```
if($this->shouldReport($exception) {
    // Send email
}
```

You can also consider to check your environment and if an exception message exists in the same if-statement.

Comment: is there another method to handle this type of issue

Comment: @satish: The parent class `Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler.php` uses the same method, so I expect the framework doesn't provide some additional magic for this.

Comment: `$this->shouldntReport($e)` does exist too

Answer (score 2):

Just to expand upon this for future visitors:

I spent far too long trying to figure out why my `validate()` method's response was broken and then what to do with the `ValidationException` to restore it.

Well, turns out the `Handler.php` class isn't as out-of-the-box friendly as you might be used to. If you dig into the parent class (`Illuminate\Foundation\Exceptions\Handler`), you'll realize that by the mere act of creating a (mostly) empty class with `report()` and `render()` methods, you are unintentionally overwriting a lot of logic-- including that which handles a list of Exceptions Laravel is set to "don't report" by default.

So, in the event you're just looking to customize some specific Exceptions and want to avoid any unintended side-effects, you *might* want to set up your render class like this:

```
public function render($request, Throwable $exception)
{
    
    if ($this->shouldntReport($exception)) {
        return parent::render($request, $exception);
    }


    // Your code here

}
```

(Obviously, checking what those default Exceptions are might be wise.)